# Collating row entries in 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array consisting of 1s and 0s.
I want to club up the 1s and 0s of each row.

```
arr = 
[[0  1  0]
[ 0  0  0]
[ 1  1  1]
[ 0  1  1]]
```

Desired output (each element is dtype str, to make sure leading zeros are not omitted)

```
[ 010 , 000 , 111 , 011 ]
```

How can I manipulate the 2d array to get this output? Is it possible in `numpy` or `regex` packages, by using their functions? Can a for loop be avoided to do this array transformation?

Comment: Do you have integers? Strings? please provide a reproducible object with the correct dtype

Comment: Each element in the 2d array is "astype(np.int64)".

Comment: yes, @mozway probably means the output. What dtype is that supposed to be?

Comment: Also what would be the final decimal output? there is probably no need to concatenate an intermediate

Comment: The dtype of the output should be int64 (same as the input). If I understood what you meant, the 4 entries 010 , 000 , 111 , 011 would be of type int64 and in base 2.

Comment: `010` is not a valid int

Comment: Okay the easiest solution then is to treat the output dtype as a string.

Comment: In that case: `[''.join(map(str, a)) for a in arr]`

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite unclear, assuming integers in and out, you could use:

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 1],
              [0, 1, 1]])

out = (a[:,::-1]*(10**np.arange(a.shape[1]))).sum(1)
```

But you won't have leading zeros…

output:

```
array([ 10,   0, 111,  11])
```

Assuming you really want to convert from binary, you should probably use [`np.packbits`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html):

```
out = np.packbits(np.pad(a, ((0,0), (8-a.shape[1],0))), axis=1, bitorder='big')
```

output:

```
array([[2],
       [0],
       [7],
       [3]], dtype=uint8)
```

or as flat version:

```
out = (np.packbits(np.pad(a, ((0,0), (8-a.shape[1],0))), axis=1, bitorder='big')
         .ravel()
       )
# array([2, 0, 7, 3], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: the np.packbits works only if the output decimal value is upto 255 (uint8). What do I do if I have value >255 that I have to collate in binary and express as decimal output?

Comment: `packbits` only works with 8 bits unsigned integers. I suggest to ask a new question explaining what you want to do with examples.

Comment: Okay thanks! The second approach by blunova isn't as small as packbits code snippet but a good workaround for packing bits where decimal value >255.

Comment: It depends if you need a vectorial solution or not. But if your goal is to get a decimal number just use my first solution with `2` as power instead of `10`: `(a[:,::-1]*(2**np.arange(a.shape[1]))).sum(1)` will give you `array([2, 0, 7, 3])`

Comment: This works well for all values (big numbers). I do not need a vectoral solution.

Comment: have you tested the `(a[:,::-1]*(2**np.arange(a.shape[1]))).sum(1)`? Works well **and** is vectorial ;)

Comment: Okay my bad. It works well and is vectoral.

Answer (score 1):

Using strings:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0,  1,  0], [ 0,  0,  0], [ 1,  1,  1], [ 0,  1,  1]])

binaries = []
for idx, row in enumerate(arr):
    strings = [str(integer) for integer in row]
    a_string = "".join(strings)
    binaries.append(a_string)

>>> binaries
>>> ['010', '000', '111', '011']
```